# Create pointe layer with table

Tags: qgis, point, coordinates, table

I have a table with 13,000 points of geographic coordinates ( degrees, minutes , seconds)

How I can create a layer of points ?

QGIS or Arcgis . it is possible to create a layer of points with coordinated geography ?

or only with decimal coordinates ?

There are many points , it will be very time consuming to convert 1-1 .

[image]